# getElementById is null when trying to access an input type="hidden"

Tags: javascript

i'm having a problem concerning acessing `<input type="hidden">` with the getElementById and getting it`s value.

Here's my function, it`s located on page 1 and serves to display my selections as well as let me go back and change them.

```
function showTerrain(terrain) {

if(document.getElementById('muni1') == null){  alert('is null'); }
else {alert('test:' + document.getElementById('muni1').value);}

  w = window.open("terrainChooser.php?terr=" + terrain + "&regID=1&muni=Rouyn-Noranda&parc=193", "", "width=500,height=450");

}
```

When showTerrain is activated, it is sent to terrainChooser.php which lets me pick 3 values and returns the information as such:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = 
   "<input readonly type='text' style='background-color:#eed8bb;border:0;' name='parcName" +    parcNum + "' value=\"" + txt + "\" />
    <input type='hidden' name='parcId" +parcNum + "' value='" + id + "' />
    <input type='hidden' name='regID" + parcNum + "' value='" + regID + "' />
    <input type='hidden' name='muni" + parcNum + "' value='" + muni +"' />";
```

I know for a fact the Id i'm searching by is unique as it appears as such in the browser (firebug):

```
<td id="parcSelected1"><input type="text" value="Forum" name="parcName1" style="background-color: rgb(238, 216, 187); border: 0pt none;" readonly="">
  <input type="hidden" value="193" name="parcId1">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="regID1">
  <input type="hidden" value="Rouyn-Noranda" name="muni1"></td>
```

Not sure what to do... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `name` attribute instead of the `id` one. Change

```
name='parcId" +parcNum + "'
```

to

```
id='parcId" +parcNum + "'
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn`t realize i wasn`t sending an id.

Answer (score 1):

maybe i'm blind but... in your html-code, there is no element with id "muni1" - just one with this **name**. change:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Rouyn-Noranda" name="muni1">
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Rouyn-Noranda" name="muni1" id="muni1">
```

Answer (score 0):

The "getElementById()" function operates on element **id** values, not element **name** values. (Well, Internet Explorer thinks that "name" and "id" mean the same thing, but it's simply incorrect. Other browsers don't agree.)

Give the element an "id":

```
<input type="hidden" value="Rouyn-Noranda" name="muni1" id="muni1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting "name" not "id"

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(elementID)
```

has to point to the ID field of a element, I believe you are pointing to the name attribute. That only works in IE.

```
<input type="hidden" value="Rouyn-Noranda" name="muni1"></td>
```

needs to be

```
<input type="hidden" value="Rouyn-Noranda" id="muni1"></td>
```